# javaFX css styling for an array of text not working

Tags: css, javafx, javafx-css

I have a CSS file that styles my application MusicPlayer. I'm trying to style my array of javafx.scene.text.Text named sliderText. However nothing works. even when i use `.text` it styles the text of everything else EXCEPT my array of sliderText. any ideas how to get this working?
thanks

heres my declaration of slider text =

```
public static javafx.scene.text.Text[] sliderText = new Text[10];
```

also general question, how do i use .setID() in both javafx and CSS?

I've tried doing the following:

```
 .text {
 -fx-font-size: 32px;
  -fx-font-family: "Arial Black";
-fx-fill: #818181;
-fx-effect: innershadow( three-pass-box , rgba(0,0,0,0.7) , 6, 0.0 , 0 , 2 );
}
```

And that changes literally everything except what i want it to

Comment: Can you show the relevant CSS? And are you setting a style class on your `sliderText` array elements?

Comment: I set a style class for my entire scene

Comment: That makes no sense. `Scene`s do not have style classes. Are you setting the style class on the text elements to "text" anywhere? By default, [`Text` objects have no style class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#text)

Comment: I don't think so, i've tried using setID(), but that hasn't worked, what do you mean?

Comment: The CSS you posted applies the four rules (`-fx-font-size: 32px` etc) to anything with a CSS style class of `"text"`. Did you add that style class to the text objects?

Comment: How would I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, [`Text` objects have no style class attached to them](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#text). (Only `Control`s have default style classes set.) So your rule (which applies to the style class "text"), won't apply to your text objects.

The [basic CSS tutorial for JavaFX](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/apply-css.htm#CHDGHCDG) covers all this, but briefly you need to do something like

```
for (Text text : sliderText) {
    text.getStyleClass().add("text");
}
```

either in the constructor or in the `start()` method or an initialization method (you haven't shown enough context for your code for me to know how your application is set up).

For your question:

> how do i use .setID() in both javafx and CSS?

you can do

```
someNode.setId("specialNode");
```

and then in CSS

```
#specialNode {
    /* style rules for specialNode here.... */
}
```

Ids should be unique to a single node within any scene graph.

Comment: hey thanks! so that worked, but now how would i make it so that it only does the to those objects? actually never mind i did it Thanks!!!

Comment: Use a style class other than "text", which it appears is used in some controls by default.